# Reactive Native fetch not working

Tags: react-native

Post installing android studio & react native cli, I am trying fetch functionality for the first time. I tried the POST API as given on Facebook URL as follows:

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())  // Here is the error saying, response not defined.
```

Problem: It seems, the request itself is not being posted at the endpoint URL, at all. So get error as "response not defined" at the line where response is fetch and manipulated. Thorough chrome postman tested the URL which works fine, but from react native code fetch is not working. Is it like anything else needs to be installed or configured to make fetch API work properly. Kindly help/suggest.

Thanks in advance
~Vinay

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Perhaps there's a CORS problem.

Comment: The actual URL which I am calling, is different which is working properly when tested with postman. The facebook example given above is just for reference purpose .

Comment: How does one change CORS settings in React-Native? Was there ever a solution to this problem? I see this is an issue that crops again and again slowly over the years -- 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21862

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20405

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32467

I'm suffering it now. My conjecture is a config that is automatically generated has two different competing library versions causing a conflict. This problem seemingly emerged out of no where, where a build one day works, the builds the next day break

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is JSON.stringify.**
**Use FormData instead.** No need to install, it's not 3rd party.

```
import FormData from 'FormData';

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('username', 'Andy');

...

{ 
  ... 
  body: formData 
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1: open `/<Project Folder>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.
( do not get confused because there will be two AndroidManifest.xml)

Step2: Add the line

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

(under "/manifest/application)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below fetch call,

React-native log-android //Android

or react-native log-ios // IOS

use to see response data or error details

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',},
    body: JSON.stringify({ firstParam: 'yourValue', secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'})
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
    console.log("responseData : " +responseData);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error : " +error);
});
```